# Disk Free decrease in a directory containing only live lucene indexes

Tags: java, linux, lucene, filesystems

I'm running a lucene based application on a linux system.

The application writes and read many lucene indexes under the same directory, which doesn't contain other data.

We are monitoring the indexes directory and we noticed that the disk usage as calculated by the df util grows more rapidly than that calculated by the du util.

When we terminate the application the disk usage calculated with the two utils is the same and it is the one calculated with du when the application is running.

Can you figure out which is the reason?

Comment: This question could use more information such as readings by df / du as well as memory information about the process.

Comment: what do you mean by "memory information about the process"?

Comment: Is there a dynamically growing swap file present on your system?

Comment: I have no swap file on that partition

Answer (score 0):

du calculates disk usage by traversing file directories and adding up all the file sizes.

df calculates disk usage by reading the file table index.

Make sure to run du as sudo to get a better reading so that the utility has access to all files on your system. df can calculate less free space than du because du might not have access to all the files on your system while doing its calculation.

The application must have written some read protected files to the file system while running, and deletes them on exit.

To verify that this is the case, a software that can monitor disk writes can be used to profile the application. On windows, I would use Process Monitor and filter for file creation / writes. I found a similar tool to do that on linux called [monks](https://github.com/alexandernst/monks). Don't run this on your production server. This can help you find what files the application writes, and further discover if any are read locked.

Comment: thanks for the hint but I already run the utilities as sudoer

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think sudo would even be able to read a locked file.

Comment: is there a way to list all protected files under a directory tree?

Comment: I did some research and found a tool that monitors kernel calls, and should be able to report back when an application writes data to the disk. Updated the answer. Make sure you use it on a test server.

Comment: Unfortunately this problem happens only in production server and I can't use a software like monks